# fill spinner android studio programmatically

Tags: android, spinner, fill

I need to make a custom form (displaying x fields). 
There is the way I create a spinner list object:

```
Spinner[] listeCouleurs = new Spinner[nbEquipes];
```

> listeCouleurs: is the name of the list
>
> nbEquipes: is an int, (number of teams)

And there is the elements I want to insert into the list (listeCouleurs):

```
    ArrayList<String> couleurs = new ArrayList<String>();
    couleurs.add("Rouge");
    couleurs.add("Bleu");
    couleurs.add("Vert");
    couleurs.add("Rose");
    couleurs.add("Jaune");
```

And then, there is the way I insert elements into x spinner:

```
listeCouleurs[i] = new Spinner(this);
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,listeCouleurs[i], couleurs);
```

But, there is this error:

> Error:(94, 48) error: no suitable constructor found for
>   ArrayAdapter(ConfigGame,Spinner,ArrayList) constructor
>   ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int) is not applicable (argument
>   mismatch; Spinner cannot be converted to int) constructor
>   ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,String[]) is not applicable
>   (argument mismatch; Spinner cannot be converted to int) constructor
>   ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,List) is not applicable
>   (argument mismatch; Spinner cannot be converted to int)

How to resolve this problem ?

Regards

Comment: You have the answer written in the error message. It requires the most basic general programming knowledge to solve this. Please learn the very basics before you start asking questions on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of the ArrayAdapter constructor should be an int not a Spinner

Example call:

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray); //selected item will look like a spinner set from XML
spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

For more information on the possible constructor arguments see:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

Comment: I'm ok with this, but the problem is that I'm currently creating spinner programmatically, not with the XML...

Comment: The second argument is an indicator to the spinner of how it is going to be shown. `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` is internal to Android

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include these two lines after you initialize the adapter:

```
spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with a compilation error of an unsuitable Constructor being available.